# Is there a way to scan a collection with aggregate until a specific record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to get all the records that happended **after** a record that I will compute in my aggregate.

let assume I have theses records :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd61"), "ids" : 2581571270, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:02.474Z") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd62"), "ids" : 2581571270, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:12.474Z") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd63"), "ids" : 2581571270, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:22.474Z") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd64"), "ids" : 2581571271, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:12.474Z") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd65"), "ids" : 2581571271, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:32.474Z") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd65"), "ids" : 2581571272, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:42.474Z") },
```

I would like to get all the records that happended **after** (according to `dt` field) the **last** record with `ids: 2581571270`.

In my example, I will get :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd65"), "ids" : 2581571271, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:32.474Z") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58fdb4f6c2cb84c28812fd65"), "ids" : 2581571272, "idc" : 200353375, "dt" : ISODate("2017-04-24T08:19:42.474Z") },
```

I guess that the most optimised way would be to request from a `{dt: -1}` index until I got a record with `ids: 2581571270`.

Is there a way to perform such a request in mongodb aggregate ?

Comment: That sounds like an inefficient way of finding the data you're after. Would it not be easier to do it in two queries: first, find the dt value for the last record with that ids; second, list all records with a greater dt.

Comment: @Vince : Thank for your comment, you're right, but I have a problem with a two queries solution (wich I have now). My mongodb reads are set in nearest and sometimes (because of mongoid...), I have a host switch between the two queries and this is a real problem for the following treatment.